# Klaxon parse null

Tags: kotlin, klaxon

I have issue when using `Klaxon 5.5`

Class :

```
data class QRResponse(
   @field:SerializedName("qrType")
   val qrType: String? = null,

   @field:SerializedName("qrData")
   val qrData: String? = null
)
```

Code :

```
val dataContents = result.contents
Log.d("ScanQRData", "result.contents : $dataContents")

val dataQR = Klaxon().parse<QRResponse>(dataContents)
Log.d("ScanQRData", "dataQR : $dataQR")
```

Result :

> ScanQRData: result.contents : {"qrType": "product", "qrData":"352307811"}

> ScanQRData: dataQR : QRResponse(qrType=null, qrData=null)

Any suggestion what happened to `qrType` and `qrData` null after parse from `Klaxon`?

Answer (score 1):

Klaxon doesn't process `@field:SerializedName` annotation (where you have imported it from?). The correct way to customize mapping between your JSON documents and Kotlin objects in Klaxon is [`@Json` annotation](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#the-json-annotation):

```kotlin
data class QRResponse(
    @Json(name = "qrType")
    val qrType: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "qrData")
    val qrData: String? = null
)
```